# Statistical methods for overcoming residual confounding with administrative health data

Tags: regression, bayesian, causality, confounding, causal-diagram

I have extensive administrative health data (general patient demographics + medical information, place of residence, many study years, few outcome measures) that have limited variables for effectively controlling for confounding. Thus, usual methods like multiple regression are not sufficient for getting unbiased results from analyses. However, I have read/hear about more advanced statistical techniques that allow better controlling of confounding (e.g. using a conditional regional or temporal variance of an X on Y).

**Could you please provide names of statistical techniques that I should google for?**

My own research lead to these techniques:

- Use of causal analysis (DAGs) (I know it only works out when my DAG is correct).
- Front-door criterion
- Instrumental variable
- ...

PS! Bayesian methods are also anticipated.

Comment: The front-door criterion is a DAG technique, as is the backdoor adjustment. You can also try stratified analysis or inverse probability weighting. The instrumental variable approach is closely related to 2-stage least squares, so that's something else to search. I strongly recommend trying to come up with a good DAG that models your situation well. It opens a lot of doors to analysis.

Comment: Check out [Matthey et al. (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ssmph.2019.100526) for a nice discussion of alternatives. Note that stratified analysis and inverse probability weighting rely on the same identification assumptions as regression adjustment, so if you know regression will not be enough to control confounding, then those methods will not be either. IV and diff-in-diff might be good options; otherwise, you can try sensitivity analysis for unobserved confounding.